# Suppose $\mu$ is not an eigenvalue of A. Show that the equation $x'= Ax + e^{\mu t}b$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $\mu$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. Show that the equation $x'= Ax + e^{\mu t}b$ has a solution of the form $\varphi(t) = ve^{\mu t}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi(t) = ve^{\mu t}$ is a solution to

$x' = Ax + e^{\mu t} b, \tag{1}$

then

$\phi'(t) = \mu v e^{\mu t} = A\phi(t) + be^{\mu t} = e^{\mu t} A v + e^{\mu t} b, \tag{2}$

so

$\mu v = Av + b, \tag{3}$

or

$(\mu - A)v = b. \tag{4}$

(4) is a *necessary* condition for $\phi(t) = ve^{\mu t}$ to solve (1).  In the event that $\mu$ is not an eignvalue of $A$, then $A - \mu$ is nonsingular, hence for any $b$ there is a $v$ such that (4) holds.  Then we can run the steps (1)-(4) in reverse order; multiplying (3) by $e^{\mu t}$ yields (2), showing $\phi(t) = ve^{\mu t}$ solves (1).  The condition (4) is thus also *sufficient* when $\mu$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: (4) seems a slight abuse of notation. Shouldn't it be $(\mu I-A)v...$ since it seems from context that $\mu$ is a scalar and $A$ is a matrix. Good answer otherwise!

Comment: @Daryl:  technically, you are correct, I guess; but the abuse of notation is indeed *very slight*, since for any $v$,  $\mu v$ as scalar-vector multiplication and $\mu I v$ as the action of the operator $\mu I$ on $v$ are indistinguishable.  I guess subtracting $A$ from $\mu$ *could* be problematic, but if $\mu$ is understood as an operator sending $v \to \mu v$ then I think any confusion vanishes.  So yeah, it's abusive, *barely*.  My take on it anyway.  Good point though!

Comment: @Daryl:  actually, I'm pretty sure I've seen other authors or much greater mathematical stature than myself "abuse" this same notation similarly.  So I guess I can forgive myself!  This monkey see, this monkey do!